# Рекомендации по созданию пространств имён

Tags: c#, code-style

Привет, Хэшкод!

Я пишу библиотеку классов для работы с графикой. Всего в ней порядка сотни различных классов, и для поддержки внутренней структуризации очень удобно раскидывать эти классы по пространствам имен: отдельно графический примитивы, отдельно цветовые палитры, и пр. Всего около пятнадцати namespace'ов по 3-10 классов в каждом.

Но *использование* этой библиотеки обычно требует задействовать объекты из большинства категорий, и в итоге пользователь вынужден подключать по ~10 namespace'ов на каждый использующий библиотеку файл.

Какое из двух зол мне выбрать? Какие по этому поводу есть рекомендации?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Ваш текущий подход - *плохой* (если я правильно его понял), поскольку любое переименование папки приведет к необходимости каскадно просматривать все классы и менять неймспейсы по необходимости.
- Хорошим считается подход, когда название папок соответствует названию неймспейса - тогда структуризация производится только с помощью неймспейсов, а структура папок получается из нее автоматически. Такой подход, кстати, по дефолту форсирует `Resharper`.
- Пятнадцать неймспейсов для небольшой (?) библиотеки - вроде как перебор, однако в большом количестве неймспейсов нет ничего плохого. Встроенные средства `Visual Studio` и `Resharper` вполне себе справляются с автоматическим резолвингом неймспейсов, а сколько у вас в начале файла будет `using'ов`, в общем-то, никого не волнует.

> Другое дело, что потенциально большое количество неймспейсов может свидетельствовать о не очень аккуратном дизайне вашей библиотеки. Посмотрите, возможно, можно сократить количество главных неймспейсов до 2-3 и обойтись вложенными типа `MyLibrary.Utilities.FileOperations`.

Comment: Хороший ответ. Хотел бы от себя еще подытожить, что правил разделения на пространства имен как таковых нет даже в гайдлайнах и что в общем случае нужно просто делать то, что лучше будет представлять создаваемые вами абстракции и сохранять их целостность. Количество `using`'ов никого никогда не волнует - оные обычно вставляются автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

Как я сам поступаю в данный момент.

Все классы держу в трех неймспейсах, а внутреннюю структуризацию произвожу с помощью папок. В итоге обе задачи решены, но нарушается синхронность между иерархиями классов и файлов, что тоже не супер.